# Minimum permissions for a Salesforce Integration license user to create Users and assign permission sets

Tags: integration, permissions, user-profile

I am setting up a new Salesforce Integration user  (one of the 5 free licenses) to act as the running user for our corporate onboarding/offboarding systems

- Username `onboard-offboard-integration@mycompany.com`
- Profile: `Salesforce API Only System Integrations`
- Permission Set License: `Salesforce API Integration`
- Permission Set Group: `OnboardOffboard` containing these permissions

  - `Api Only`
  - `Assign Permission Set`
  - `Manage Internal User`
  - `View All Users`

When I use the REST Describe API, I discover that `User.ProfileId` and `User.UserRoleId` are not available to `onboard-offboard-integration@mycompany.com`. Hence, new Users can't be created because `ProfileId` is a required field.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The [Object Reference doc for User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm?q=user) is silent on what permission is needed for field `ProfileId`. It does say

> To create or update a User record, you must have the `Manage Internal Users` permission. `and I have granted that permission.`

- [The Object Reference doc for Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm?q=profile) states that you need `View Setup and Configuration` to see various CRUD and FLS permissions but that is not what I'm doing here
- The Permission Set License `Salesforce API Integration` does allow permissions `Manage Internal Users` and `Assign Permission Sets to Users` so that can't be the issue.

For reasons unknown to me, `User.ProfileId` and `User.UserRoleId` became visible by assigning permission `Manage Users` that in turn grants:

- `Reset User Passwords and Unlock Users`
- `View All Users`
- `Manage Profiles and Permission Sets`
- `Assign Permission Sets`
- `Manage Roles`
- `Manage IP Addresses`
- `Manage Sharing`
- `View Setup and Configuration`
- `View Roles and Role Hierarchy`
- `Manage Internal Users`
- `Manage Password Policies`
- `Manage Login Access Policies`
- `Manage Multi-Factor Authentication in User Interface`

I then starting backing out those permissions to see which one was required for exposing `User.ProfileId`

| Remove Permission | Is User.ProfileId viz? | Is User.UserRoleId Viz? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Manage Users | YES | YES |
| Manage Profiles and PS | YES | YES |
| View Setup and Configuration | NO | YES |
| View Roles and Role Hierarchy | NO (see above) | NO |

I then added back `View Setup and Configuration` (which automatically sets `View Roles and Role Hierarchy`) and deleted all the other permissions granted by `Manage Users` and concluded that the minimum permissions for the creation of users and assignment of PS/PSG by an integration user are:

- `Api Only`
- `Assign Permission Set`
- `Manage Internal User`
- `View All Users` *(for doing audits)*
- `View Setup and Configuration`
- `View Roles and Role Hierarchy`

If you also need to [assign the user to a Public Group](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.creating_and_editing_groups.htm&type=5), you'll need these permissions:

- `Manage Users` - putting me right back where I started